# kubectl - error: group map

Tags: shell, jenkins, gcloud, kubectl

I'm using gcloud and am following [this](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/continuous-delivery-jenkins-container-engine) tutorial.

When my jenkins build script runs, I keep getting the following error:

```
[sample-app_master-THTSVFWGKBDNFPP7LI4FKVNKQLHORCQPEPTNT7UFIZU66SKLPGOA] Running shell script
+ kubectl --namespace=production apply -f k8s/services/
error: group map[:0xc820376b60 authorization.k8s.io:0xc820376c40 batch:0xc820376d20 componentconfig:0xc820376d90 extensions:0xc820376e00 policy:0xc820376e70 certificates.k8s.io:0xc8202cea80 federation:0xc820376af0 autoscaling:0xc820376cb0 rbac.authorization.k8s.io:0xc820376ee0 authentication.k8s.io:0xc820376fc0 apps:0xc820376bd0] is already registered
```

kubectl version: 1.6.4

Can anyone help me?

Thx.

Comment: Make sure you are running same version of Kops and Kubectl